# Required parameter $username follows optional parameter $user

Tags: php

There is a mistake here that I don't know

```
public function checkConfirmed($user = null, $username, $value)
```

Error:

> Required parameter $username follows optional parameter $user

Comment: Either remove the `= null` from the `$user` parameter, or provide defaults for those other parameters

Comment: `that I don't know`...well the error message tells you exactly what the problem is. Did you google that message to find out more? Is there something specific in the message that you don't understand?